# UV Lamp on heating system?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I have a Honeywell thermostat & keeps on flashing "change UV Lamp"

Where would I find the UV lamp installed in the system, & how do I replace it?

Answer (score 3):

Some fan coil units have UV lamps after the filter to disinfect the air. If your FCU doesn't have one you need to program that alarm out of the system. If you don't have a manual or can't find how to do it. You can contact Honeywell hot line and they will walk you through it.